# Syncronizing css between Eclipse and Firebug/Chrome?

Tags: css, eclipse, firefox, google-chrome, firebug

Is there any good plug-ins for synchronizing CSS from Firebug/Chrome back to css file in Eclipse?

Comment: What do you mean by synchronizing? Live updates without hitting refresh, or modifying .css files with browser development tools?

Comment: Live updates I've with livereload, but what I want is any changes done in firebug is updating file itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FireDiff](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firediff/) extension doesn't automatically sync your changes back to the source file in your development environment, but it will track the changes for you and provides the capability to save the snapshot back to your original source file.

There's also [FireFile](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefile/), but I haven't had a chance to play around with it much so not sure if it will meet your needs.